# Algorithm to find flow direction in a network

Tags: algorithm, networkx, graph-theory, physics

Imagine a bidirectional meshed network graph with multiple sinks and multiple sources.

[image]

Let's say nodes 6 and 20 are sources and nodes 4, 11, 12 and 21 are sinks in this example.
Now imagine some sort of fluid passing through this network from sources to sinks.

**Is there an algorithm to find the flow direction for any given link between two nodes?**

Comment: So bidirectional in an asymmetric way w(uv)!=w(vu) or just undirected.  
The problem sounds like the Multicut and Multicommodity Flow. One source I know is Chapter 18 Approximation Algorithm: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~vazirani/book.pdf.

Comment: looks a lot like what you have to do to calculate voltages and currents for a circuit... https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/mesh-current-method/

Comment: Almost, it's about estimating gas flows in a grid, without doing a full scale fluid dynamics simulation... But it's a good idea to check electrical engineering solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Thanks for the source @Luka, I will check it out. For now I am just looking for a solution in an undirected graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be described as a [multi-commodity flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem), like @Luka mentioned.

In multi-commodity flow problems one or more commodities need to be distributed from sources to sinks in the network. Unlike many other graph algorithms, multiple sinks and sources are allowed. The multi-commodity flow problem can be solved using linear optimization. Gurobi has a [great example script implemented in Python](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_mac/cs_netflow_py_example.html).

If you need it to work with bi-directional edges in your graph, just include both directions when initializing the edges, capacities and costs. Otherwise this example works great for the use case from the question.

For people that do not have / cannot get a Gurobi license (academic is free for a year), check out this [repo](https://github.com/aleable/McOpt) instead.